# I used redshift spectrum to query S3 data, but I am having a reserved word conflict problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I was trying to query S3 data using redshift spectrum.

The table has an `oid` column, and the table is created using the glue crawler.

I tried to fetch data using this command in redshift.

```
select * from db.table order by pid desc limit 1
```

but an error raised.

```
[XX000] ERROR: Failed to incorporate external table "db"."table" into local catalog. Error=column name "oid" conflicts with a system column name
```

It is difficult to change the files. Is there a way to solve this without changing the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.  If this were a normal table you would have to double quote reserved words used as column names.  How this extends to external table could be interesting.  Does

```
select "pid", "oid" from db.table order by pid desc limit 1;
```

work?

I'm thinking that Redshift could be expanding * into the column names before passing them to the spectrum engines.  (Or it could be something else.)  If this works it suggests expanding the columns and quoting the reserved word column names as a work around.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried, but the same error message is displayed.

Comment: Best guess but didn't work.  At this point I'd contact AWS support on "escaping reserved word column names in Spectrum".  I fear that there may not be a solution but they will know.